# .NET Standard vs multi framework targeting

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I have just been looking into the usage of .NET Standard have a question.

I have a class library which is accessed from a .NET 6 project and a .NET 4.6.1 project.  What is the difference between specifying the library framework as .NET Standard vs multi framework targetting, i.e:

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

vs

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

There is no #if contitional compilation code in the library, so just wondered if there was a difference between the 2 targeting methods, or if one was more standard than the other?